# Insert V1 code my search engine on html page

Tags: google-custom-search, google-search-api

(English is not my native language, PROMT translate)

Hello. I want to insert V1 code of my search engine on html page. The elementary example, given in the instruction of Google Custom Search Engine:

[image: Simple V1 Code]

But the search form doesn't appear:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>my site</title>
...
<head>
<body>
<div1>...</div1>
<div id='cse' style='width: 100%;'>Loading</div>
<script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('search', '1', {language: 'ru', style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  var customSearchOptions = {};
  var orderByOptions = {};
  orderByOptions['keys'] = [{label: 'Relevance', key: ''} , {label: 'Date', key: 'date'}];
  customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
  customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;
  var imageSearchOptions = {};
  imageSearchOptions['layout'] = 'google.search.ImageSearch.LAYOUT_POPUP';
  customSearchOptions['enableImageSearch'] = true;
  var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('018041543241092912643:0t1ehacm74m', customSearchOptions);
  customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
  var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
  options.enableSearchResultsOnly();
  options.setAutoComplete(true);
  customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
  function parseParamsFromUrl() {
    var params = {};
    var parts = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      var keyValuePair = parts[i].split('=');
      var key = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[0]);
      params[key] = keyValuePair[1] ?
          decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')) :
          keyValuePair[1];
    }
    return params;
  }
  var urlParams = parseParamsFromUrl();
  var queryParamName = 'q';
  if (urlParams[queryParamName]) {
    customSearchControl.execute(urlParams[queryParamName]);
  }
}, true);
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
  .gsc-control-cse {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-control-cse .gsc-table-result {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .gsc-tabHeader.gsc-tabhInactive {
    border-color: #FF9900;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-tabHeader.gsc-tabhActive {
    border-color: #E9E9E9;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border-bottom-color: #FF9900
  }
  .gsc-tabsArea {
    border-color: #FF9900;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result, .gsc-results .gsc-imageResult {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result:hover, .gsc-imageResult:hover {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:link, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:link b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:link, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:link b  {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:visited, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:visited b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:visited, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:visited b {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:hover, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:hover b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:hover, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:hover b {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:active, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:active b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:active, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:active b {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gsc-cursor-page {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  a.gsc-trailing-more-results:link {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-webResult .gs-snippet, .gs-imageResult .gs-snippet, .gs-fileFormatType {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl, .gs-imageResult div.gs-visibleUrl {
    color: #008000;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-short {
    color: #008000;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-short  {
    display: none;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-long {
    display: block;
  }
  .gs-promotion div.gs-visibleUrl-short {
    display: none;
  }
  .gs-promotion div.gs-visibleUrl-long  {
    display: block;
  }
  .gsc-cursor-box {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-results .gsc-cursor-box .gsc-cursor-page {
    border-color: #E9E9E9;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gsc-results .gsc-cursor-box .gsc-cursor-current-page {
    border-color: #FF9900;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result.gsc-promotion {
    border-color: #336699;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-completion-title {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gsc-completion-snippet {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:link,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:link *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:link  {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:visited,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:visited *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:visited {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:hover,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:hover *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:hover  {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:active,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:active *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:active {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion .gs-snippet, .gs-promotion .gs-title .gs-promotion-title-right, .gs-promotion .gs-title .gs-promotion-title-right * {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .gs-promotion .gs-visibleUrl,.gs-promotion .gs-visibleUrl-short  {
    color: #008000;
  }
</style>
<div2>...</div2>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need to make for a correct insert of a code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have selected results only, which will not display the search form. This way is designed to run from the address bar. E.g. `http://www.example.com/yourSearchPage?q=searchterm`

This should then display the search results on that page.